# Combine two columns if one column str.contain specific characters in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a small test data as follows:

```
   id city                                           address
0   1   HK           55 Peng Sui Road Che Sham Man Hong Kong
1   2   HK        77 Kun Chok Fong San Tsuen Noi Fok Kowloon
2   3   HK         48 Nut Chok Lou Tsa Sik Kowloon Hong Kong
3   4   HK          Block 69, Hai Ang Court Aberdeen Kowloon
4   5   HK  40 Tsang Tai Kit Street Wak Luet New Territories
```

If `Hong Kong` is not contained in `address`, then I want to create a new column `detailed_add` by combining `df['address'] + ', ' + df['city']`:

```
   id city                                           address                                       detailed_add
0   1   HK           55 Peng Sui Road Che Sham Man Hong Kong            55 Peng Sui Road Che Sham Man Hong Kong
1   2   HK        77 Kun Chok Fong San Tsuen Noi Fok Kowloon     77 Kun Chok Fong San Tsuen Noi Fok Kowloon, HK
2   3   HK         48 Nut Chok Lou Tsa Sik Kowloon Hong Kong          48 Nut Chok Lou Tsa Sik Kowloon Hong Kong
3   4   HK          Block 69, Hai Ang Court Aberdeen Kowloon       Block 69, Hai Ang Court Aberdeen Kowloon, HK
4   5   HK  40 Tsang Tai Kit Street Wak Luet New Territories  40 Tsang Tai Kit Street Wak Luet New Territori..., HK
```

To filter rows: `df[~df['address'].str.contains('Hong Kong', na = False)]`.

```
   id city                                           address
1   2   HK        77 Kun Chok Fong San Tsuen Noi Fok Kowloon
3   4   HK          Block 69, Hai Ang Court Aberdeen Kowloon
4   5   HK  40 Tsang Tai Kit Street Wak Luet New Territories
```

How could I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where()`

```py
df['detailed_add'] = np.where(df['address'].str.contains('Hong Kong'), df['address'], df['address'] + ', ' + df['city'])
```

```
print(df)

   id city                                           address                                       detailed_add
0   1   HK           55 Peng Sui Road Che Sham Man Hong Kong            55 Peng Sui Road Che Sham Man Hong Kong
1   2   HK        77 Kun Chok Fong San Tsuen Noi Fok Kowloon     77 Kun Chok Fong San Tsuen Noi Fok Kowloon, HK
2   3   HK         48 Nut Chok Lou Tsa Sik Kowloon Hong Kong          48 Nut Chok Lou Tsa Sik Kowloon Hong Kong
3   4   HK          Block 69, Hai Ang Court Aberdeen Kowloon       Block 69, Hai Ang Court Aberdeen Kowloon, HK
4   5   HK  40 Tsang Tai Kit Street Wak Luet New Territories  40 Tsang Tai Kit Street Wak Luet New Territori...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```py
df["new_column"] = df["address"] if df["address"].str.contains(r'\bHong Kong\b') else df["address"] + ', HK'
```

The above logic just pulls over the current address if it already contains Hong Kong in it.  Otherwise, it appends `, HK` to the end of the current address.

Answer (score 1):

```
df["detailed_add"]=np.where(~df.address.str.contains("Hong Kong"), df['address'].str.cat(df['city'], sep=","),df['address'])

df.head(2)

 id city                                     address  \
0   1   HK     55 Peng Sui Road Che Sham Man Hong Kong   
1   2   HK  77 Kun Chok Fong San Tsuen Noi Fok Kowloon   

                                    detailed_add  
0        55 Peng Sui Road Che Sham Man Hong Kong  
1  77 Kun Chok Fong San Tsuen Noi Fok Kowloon,HK
```